# Connecting mirror heating pads to switch in bathroom

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm trying to wire mirror heating pads that are placed behind the mirror. The heating pads have two wires coming out of them. The wires are blue and brown although i think they should be black.

Im replacing one of the outlets in the mirror with a switch. I want to connect the heating pads to the switch.

The old outlet is wired as a series to three other outlets. As you can see in the picture, i have 2 ground, 2 neutral and 2 live cables sticking out of it.

How can i connect the pads to the switch and maintain the other three outlets as serie?

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

[image: current wiring]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the two browns (L) to your switch: supply on one side of switch, heater on other side of switch.  Join the two blues (N). Join the two greens (PE).  Make sure your method of joining the wires conforms to your country's wiring standard.

By the way, Brown is Line per IEC; Blue is Neutral.  Line is black in US and other countries not aligning with IEC.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start, you need three **WAGO 224-112 2-Leiter-Leuchtenklemmen** (or similar from another supplier) [image: WAGO 224-112 2-Leiter-Leuchtenklemme] These have two clamps for rigid copper wires on the front, and one clamp for flexible wire on the back.

- Connect both green-yellow wires to the first clamp.
- Connect both rigid blue wires to the second clamp, and the flexible blue wire from the heater to the backside of the second clamp.
- Connect the brown flexible wire from the heater to the backside of the third clamp, and a short rigid piece of black or brown wire to the frontside of the third clamp.
- Connect this open end rigid black or brown wire to the output of the switch.
- Connect both rigid brown wires from your existing installation to the input of the switch.

Don't try to put the flexible wires into the switch clamps. This won't work, they are only meant for rigid wires.